# Download manager android!!! Как взять "общий" прогресс

Tags: android, download, manager

В приложении загружаются видео файлы с помощью Download manager. Необходимо отображать прогресс внутри активити. Как отображать общий прогресс, если загружаются несколько файлов? Допустим загружаются 2 файла: первый загрузился на 50%, второй на 25% средний (т.е. общий) прогресс = 37,5%. Можно ли в Download manager взять общий прогресс всех загружаемых файлов, а не по отдельности?

Comment: Я предполагаю, что в нём такого понятия не существует и вам придётся его ввести, считая самостоятельно на основе прогресса отдельных файлов. Который, кстати, не всегда может существовать. Прогресс скачивания отдельных файлов вы уже научились получать?

Comment: Да научился. Я надеялся, что есть готовый метод или  какой нибудь прием для решения данной задачи.